# Apex - Two buttons on same page, branching to different locations

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have a page with two regions (DIY forms), with two buttons - page structure shown below. I want these buttons to branch to different locations, but am struggling (using Apex 4.2).

The buttons both 'SUBMIT', and I have tried but failed using:

1. Creating two branches, one on 'SUBMIT (Button 1)' and other 'SUBMIT (Button 2)'
2. Creating processes on each button press, using the following code (X different on each):

   ```
   BEGIN

   htp.init;
   owa_util.redirect_url('f?p=&APP_ID.:X:&APP_SESSION.);
   apex_application.stop_apex_engine;

   END;
   ```

For both approaches, after one button is pressed, it simply uses the action/branch listed higher on the page editing screen. I also tried dynamic actions, but no luck - PS/SQL syntax errors using the code above?

There MUST be an easy answer to this!

---

Page Structure

- Region 1

  - Button 1
- Region 2

  - Button 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- > First, You should assign your SUBMIT Buttons different **NAMES** for each region so you can identify what process will execute if such button is pressed.

for example:

SUBMIT_region1 => SUBMIT button for region 1
SUBMIT_region2 => SUBMIT button for region 2

- > Create Branch:
  >   Branch Point => On Submit After Processing ;
  >   Branch Type  => Branch To Page URL, if you want to branch to different page in the application;
  >   Choose Destination Page;
  >   Lastly, **WHEN BUTTON PRESSED** => Select Your Button Name.

Comment: Thanks @brenners1302, this was my issue! Unfortunately, I had not renamed the second button - doh.

Comment: @PidgeyBAWK it's also worth to note that button names will set the `:REQUEST` value to their name. Hence why 2 buttons with the same name will react the same. Also, using the buttons to conditionalize a process or branch will check this request value and not some internal id or anything. Effectively, using the "when button pressed" is adding another condition like `:REQUEST = 'SUBMIT'`. Just some more background-info.

Answer (score 0):

If you create two branches with propertues:

```
"Target type" : Page in ths Application
"Page"        : your desired page number
"When Button Pressed" : your button name
```

Or you can rewrite your processes:

```
"When Button Pressed" : your button name OR

"Condition Type" : Request=Expression1
"Expression 1" : your button request (button name)
```

Or you even can create unconditional process to set some hidden field value to target page number and then create branch where "Page" property set to "&HIDDEN_FIELD_NAME." This will be replaced with current hidden filed value.